# ¿Cómo ingresar hora en formato de 24 horas?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este código, y al ingresar la hora, ejemplo 13, la convierte en 01 y luego debo elegir si es AM o PM, después que eligo si me la muestra en e formato deseado, con javascript

```
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2 mb-1 col-lg-3"  
    type="text" name="TimeStart" placeholder="Desde (Hora)" onclick="ocultarError();" 
    onfocus="(this.type='time')" onblur="(this.type='text')">
```

Intenté cambiando `type="text"` por `type="time"` y no funciona, requiero poder ingresarla en formato 24 horas.

Comment: El formato que use el campo tipo `time` depende de la configuración local en tu sistema. El navegador la toma de ahí y la página la va a usar. [Documentación MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time)

Comment: Muchas gracias!